# How to solve this error: package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest#overrides[0]: Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, eslint, yarnpkg

Unable to launch my app using `sudo yarn build` I am getting this error:

```
package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest#overrides[0]:
   Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
```

What would be a solution for this error?

Comment: What should come from https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest, but I'm without a [mre] it's hard to say why your specific setup doesn't work.

Comment: As a temporary solution you could remove  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }, from your package.json

Answer (score 19):

Update Package.json(Remove "react-app/jest" from extends array

```
"eslintConfig": { "extends": [ "react-app" ] },
```

if you are using eslintconfig delete that or remove the react-app/jest  from there extends array and keep only react-app
Run npm install and check again It should work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with npm.

Resolution took editing package.json

Find and remove the whole eslintConfig

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
```

also I had devDependencies that needed to be removed.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.2"
  }
```

I ran "npm install". The error cleared.  Then I added all of the above back into the package.json.  I ran "npm install" again with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me. The reason the error came up is because I had the same value in my CSS file for a media query as in my inline styling.

I was trying to set the font-size to 18px in the media query for mobile development and it was the same value in my inline styling. When I changed the values so that they were not the same the error went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34245173)

Answer (score -1):

This is due to error in node_modules
Delete node_modules from file directory manually and try running this code in terminal of VSCode :

```
npm install
```

Comment: it won't solve with npm install